# Setting focus to a div after replace

Tags: jquery, html

I want to shift focus to a div (#tab2) after a location.replace has called the function but I'm struggling to get it to work.

```
function deleteItem(parent) {
        window.location.replace(pageContext +
                '/delete/item/' +
                $('#itemTabs').tabs( "option", "active" ) + '/' +
                $('#accordion2').accordion( "option", "active" ) + '/' +
                parent.find('.a-itemId').val());
    }
```

This function deletes the item and once it has done so I need to redirect the page to a specific div rather than refresh the whole page. What would be the best method to get this to work?

Comment: I'd recommend using AJAX.

Comment: Which approach is used for  `<div>` element to be able to gain focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ajax. jQuery has a very easy to understand implementation of ajax. Visit [this link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for more information.

You can use it this way:

```
var url = pageContext +
          '/delete/item/' +
          $('#itemTabs').tabs( "option", "active" ) + '/' +
          $('#accordion2').accordion( "option", "active" ) + '/' +
          parent.find('.a-itemId').val();

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function () {
        // this function is called after your call has succeeded.
    }
});
```